# C# Merge Two SortedLists (Union?)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sortedlist

I'm looking to speed up a piece of code that merges two `SortedLists`.

C# 4.0 generic `SortedList`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.100).aspx

```
public Trait getTrait(decimal thisValue)
{       
    if (ParentStructure != null && ParentStructure.RankedTraits.Count > 0)
    {
        SortedList<decimal, Trait> tempTraits = this.RankedTraits;

        // Improve here (union?)
        foreach (KeyValuePair<decimal, Trait> kvp in (ParentStructure.RankedTraits))
        {
            if (!tempTraits.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)) 
            { 
                tempTraits.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value); 
            }
        }
        return _getTrait(tempTraits, thisValue);
        }
    }
    return _getTrait(_rankTraits, thisValue);
}
```

I'm thinking that a union instead of the `foreach` loop would be faster but I don't know how to implement a union on a `SortedList`. If someone could help me out with that I would appreciate it.

Also, if there is a better way of doing this overall I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Just an idea, but according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1754080/551322), it might help if you sort input collection.

Comment: Thanks, the data being input is coming from sorted lists so that should make it presorted -- looking at that though I may want to switch to a SortedDictionary.

Comment: Why are you looking to speed up this code? Does it perform poorly?

Comment: No, it runs fine - It just seems like there should be a better way. This is a key part of my code and I just need to have it run as quickly as possible.

Comment: So people keep editing my description and removing C# from the title (I think that should stay) and the last person also removed the link to `SortedList` on MSDN.  Can anyone give me some insight to why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that I can think of merging two `SortedList` instances would be to union them, then convert to a lookup, then grab the first element of the lookup collection to make a dictionary.

I would need to make a dictionary because the `SortedList` only supports one-by-one adds. So the only other option would be to inject a dictionary into the `SortedList` constructor.

Bottom line: I think your current code is pretty decent as it is. LINQ can help reduce the code to about 2 lines (or one if you're a masochist).

```
SortedList<decimal, Traits> listA = new SortedList<decimal, Traits>();
SortedList<decimal, Traits> listB = new SortedList<decimal, Traits>();

listA.Add(1m, new Traits { FieldName = "One" });
listA.Add(2m, new Traits { FieldName = "Two" });
listA.Add(3m, new Traits { FieldName = "Three" });

listB.Add(1m, new Traits { FieldName = "One" });
listB.Add(4m, new Traits { FieldName = "Four" });
listB.Add(5m, new Traits { FieldName = "Five" });

var listUnion = listA.Union(listB).ToLookup(k => k.Key, v => v.Value)
                     .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.First());
var listMerged = new SortedList<decimal, Traits>(listUnion);
```

Comment: Thanks -- that answers my questions about unions -- however it doesn't make my code faster (probably because of having to convert it back to a SortedList) so I wont me using it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I kind of thought so, too. The issue is that the `SortedList.Union` doesn't seem to respect the `IEqualityComparer`. If it did, it **might** be a tiny bit more performant, because the conversion to lookup would impact the later conversion to dictionary.  It also kind of sucks that `SortedList` doesn't innately support the addition of a range of `KeyValuePairs` rather than just one at a time.

Comment: Yeah, this actually does a lot more looping than the original code, because that's what linq does in the background.

Comment: @code4life "It also kind of sucks that SortedList doesn't innately support the addition of a range of KeyValuePairs rather than just one at a time."   --

That's what I was hoping someone could point me towards.  But at least I feel a little bit more confidant in my programming skills now.  =)

Answer (score 2):

SortedSet has a UnionWith method that does what you are asking.  I created my own implementation of SortedSet and it performs very quickly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411939.aspx

Nevermind, I re-read your question and you are using the list implementation; however, if you can figure out a way to create an EqualityComparer instead of using a specific key, it might be possible to adapt a SortedSet to your purpose.

Comment: Thanks, but SortedSet & SortedList are not the same thing. It's the Key/Value that is messing me up and SortedSet doesn't have a key.  -- Also I am hoping to get some sort of example on how to implement it. I can do searches on my own.

Comment: Indeed, my apologies.  However, looking at your example code, are you trying to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: No duplicates keys -- I don't believe a SortedList can have duplicate keys anyway.  Duplicate Values are fine.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I guess my implementation is slightly different than yours.  I use a date as the key in my sorted set, so no duplicates allowed and I can pull out by date.  You can ignore this answer :-)