# Appropriate list-like sorted data structure

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-4.5, time-complexity

I am looking for a list-like data structure with the following properties:

1. Generic, i.e., `DataStructure<T>`, where `T` is generic
2. Multiple different instances of `T` which are considered equal by `IComparable<T>` must be allowed to be present in the list at the same time; their order can be arbitrary (even change), but they must come after "smaller" instances of `T` and before "larger" instances of `T`
3. `O(log(n))` insertion time complexity (or faster)
4. `O(log(n))` retrieval time complexity (or faster)
5. Possibility to access the first/last element with `O(1)` time complexity
6. Possibility to access the predecessor/successor of an element with `O(1)`  time complexity
7. Available without the use of additional libraries

I do not care about removal time complexity since elements only need to be deleted very rarely. I also do not care about space complexity.

I know that there is no data structure which fulfills all properties, but the ones from the BCL (which look like they could do what I need at first glace) seem to have too many disadvantages:

- `SortedSet<T>` does not allow multiple instances which are considered the same by `IComparable<T>` (2) and does not have predecessor/successor functions (6)
- `SortedSet<T, List<T>>` (with only one "representative" indexing instance of `T`) would require quite some additional (ugly) code, and there is still no predecessor/successor function (6)
- `SortedList<T, T>` is too slow for insertion (3)
- `SortedDictionary<T, T>` does not allow multiple instances which are considered the same by `IComparable<T>` (2) and does not allow accessing the first/last element directly (5), nor does it have predecessor/successor functions (6)
- Inheriting from `List<T>` and keeping it sorted would possibly be an option, but I'd rather use something that is built-in (7) due to the implementation effort and the potentially poor performance

Am I overlooking something? There seem to be no other relevant data structures for my use case (I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128636/net-data-structures-arraylist-list-hashtable-dictionary-sortedlist-sorted) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376965/when-to-use-a-sortedlisttkey-tvalue-over-a-sorteddictionarytkey-tvalue?rq=1), among others). Is there another data structure which I did not consider?

Comment: Perhaps a skip list would be a good fit? I don't know of any "built-in" implementation, though; why don't you want to take on additional dependencies?

Comment: @Cameron: Licensing may become an issue.

Comment: Why not just add the Hash to the IComparable on a SortedSet?

Comment: @Blam: I tried that, but when calling `GetViewBetween` with two "identical" objects, I have a 50% chance of getting an exception thrown since `GetViewBetween` expects the smaller object first. Depending on their hash, this is only true half the time (statistically speaking).

Comment: I am wondering if you could not get lower to return a hash of zero and higher to return a hash int32max

Comment: @Blam: The probability should be zero, i.e., there should never be a case where an insertion fails.

Comment: I was not saying anything about insert.  I clearly have nothing of value to add.

Comment: @Blam: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your comment then. What were you suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to relax 5 and 6 then you might be able to use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but unfortunately I cannot relax those two requirements.