# C# Set Base Object in Derived Class

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```cs
public class MyDict: ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>
{
    public GenerateContent()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            this.TryAdd(i, i.ToString());
        }

        base = this.OrderByDescending(v => v.Key); // --> Error
    }
}
```

After adding some values to the base class, I would like to sort it. But `ConcurrentDictionary<>` does not offer a `Sort()` method. Therefore I used `OrderByDescending()`. But this method does not change the original object. It returns a new one instead.

Is there a way to sort the dictionary?

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` is not an ordered collection. Even if your code worked, it still would not guarantee that the `Keys` will be returned in the proper order in the future. You might want to look into [OrderedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) and then implement your own thread-safety. Alternatively, you could build `MyDict` via [composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) and order the keys/elements when requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three problems with the approach you're attempting:

1. First and foremost, [as commenter Rob points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145350/c-sharp-set-base-object-in-derived-class/35145495#comment58010470_35145350), `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not preserve order. It has no mechanism for ordering, and if it did, that order wouldn't be guaranteed in the future.
2. The `base` identifier, like `this`, is read-only. You cannot assign it.
3. The type of `base` would be `ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>` (in your example), but the type of the `OrderByDescending()` method's return value is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` and so would not be assignable to the variable `base` anyway.

If you want an ordered dictionary, you'll need to use something else, e.g. `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`. Of course, neither of those are thread-safe, so you would need to take additional steps to make use of them safely if they are used concurrently.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems like I will be using `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`. As it is faster. Here is a comparison of the both:
[When to use a SortedList<TKey, TValue> over a SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376965/when-to-use-a-sortedlisttkey-tvalue-over-a-sorteddictionarytkey-tvalue)