# Which class type should I use for sorted collection with key updating and value lookup

Tags: c#, sorting, unity-game-engine, collections

I am making a game in Unity with c# code and I want a character to have something like aggro table.

It will be something like **(float, int) table** where **int** is other character id and **float** is actual aggro value.

Basically, I have few things in mind:

- The table should be sorted by float keys so I can quickly get top
  entries
- I need to be able to frequently lookup entries by its int
  value because of (3)
- I want to change float key frequently and have
  the table sorted up all the time
- I **dont** care about memory usage
  as there wont be that many entries
- I **do** care about performance of
  operations like inserting/removing/changing entries and re-sorting
  the list

I am not very experienced in C# saw few things like sortedlist/dictionary, but it doesnt seem to be optimalized for all the things I want.

Do you have any advice?

**EDIT:** Not sure if I did a good job at explaining what I want to achieve. It might be very similar to a table of football player names and number of goals they scored during the season. I will frequently ask for "most productive players" and also I will frequently update their scores by looking up their names and changing their stats, needing the table to be sorted all the time.

Comment: Side note : Never use floats as keys, they are not meant to be exact, which means retrieving your key-value pair will be a nightmare, using an int as a key you could use https://www.dotnetperls.com/sorteddictionary or   https://www.dotnetperls.com/sortedlist

Comment: Made an edit to further clarify.

Comment: How's the aggro value being used? Is it based on player range from creature or damage dealt to creature?

Comment: Damage dealt. No need to deal with range.

Comment: It is used just for sorting targets once the monster enters combat.

Comment: Just added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `List<Character>`, or an array excluding the player's character. You keep the `List<Character>` sorted with the highest aggro value at the front. To keep everything sorted every frame you run [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) first. Once a `Character` has a lower aggro value than the player's aggro threshhold you escape out of the method.

If aggro is above the threshold just run the aggro check.

You could extend this to work for multiplayer by having a `List<Player>`.
Something like:

```
void quicksort(List<Enemy> enemies, int first, int last)
{
   int left = first;
   int right = last;
   int pivot = first;
   first++;

   while (last >= first)
   {
       if(enemies[first].Aggro >= enemies[pivot].Aggro &&
           enemies[last].Aggro < enemies[pivot].Aggro)
           swapp(enemies, first, last)
       else if(enemies[first].Aggro >= enemies[pivot].Aggro)
         last--;
       else if(enemies[last].Aggro < colliders[pivot].Aggro)
         first++;
       else
       {
            last--;
            first++;
       }
   }

   swap(enemies, pivot, last);
   pivot = last;
   if(pivot > left)
      quicksort(enemies, left, pivot);
   if(right > pivot + 1)
     quicksort(enemies, pivot + 1, right);
}

void swap(List<Enemy> enemies, int left, right)
{
   var temp = enemies[right];
   enemies[right] = enemies[left];
   enemies[left] = temp;
}

void CheckAggro()
{
   quicksort(enemies, 0, enemies.Count - 1);
   for(int = 0; i < players.Count; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0 < enemies.Count; j++)
       {
           if(players[i].AggroThreshhold < enemies[j].Aggro)
           {
                break;
           }
           // Perform what happens when enemy is high on aggro threshold.
       }
   }
}
```

If players have different aggro thresholds you could save all of the enemies who have aggro above the minimum to a separate `List`, and then do a check against that from the player with the lowest to highest threshold. Just keep the list of players sorted with the lowest aggro threshold first.

Comment: Well I will have to use quicksort each frame for each aggro list which doesnt seem very efficient, but since there is no better answer, I will probably have to it this way.

Comment: Quicksort will have  `O(n * log n)`, and will run extremely fast if the data is mostly sorted. You could use Radix sort, but that would only be faster if you have a very large data set. Mostly, likely way more enemies than what you would have on the screen.

Comment: Ok, thanks for info on quicksort performance with near sorted data, will do it this way. Even if I would have problem with performance, I can always limit the quicksort call to every nth frame I guess.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on how you're updating your aggro values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution here in the `SortedList`. From What i could gather:
`SortedList <TKey, TValue>` has faster insertion and removal operations when it comes to sorted date.

There is a question that i think will help: [When to use a SortedList<TKey, TValue> over a SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376965/when-to-use-a-sortedlisttkey-tvalue-over-a-sorteddictionarytkey-tvalue)

hope I helped.

Comment: But given that those components are sorted by key, that would mean I would have to iterate through the entire list to change the key (or remove and insert it again with different value). That seems inefficient.