# SortedList<>, SortedDictionary<> and Dictionary<>

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, sortedlist, sorteddictionary

I find that `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implement the same interfaces.

1. When should we opt for `SortedList` and `SortedDictionary` over `Dictionary`?
2. What is the difference between `SortedList` and `SortedDictionary` in terms of application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935621/whats-the-difference-between-sortedlist-and-sorteddictionary

Answer (score 120, accepted):

1. When iterating over the elements in either of the two, the elements will be sorted. Not so with `Dictionary<T,V>`.
2. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) addresses the difference between `SortedList<T,V>` and `SortedDictionary<T,V>`:

> The SortedDictionary(TKey, TValue) generic class is a [binary search
>   tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) with O(log n) retrieval, where n is the number of elements in
>   the dictionary. In this respect, it is similar to the SortedList(TKey,
>   TValue) generic class. The two classes have similar object models, and
>   both have O(log n) retrieval. Where the two classes differ is in
>   memory use and speed of insertion and removal:
>
> SortedList(TKey, TValue) uses less memory than SortedDictionary(TKey,
>   TValue).
>
> SortedDictionary(TKey, TValue) has faster insertion and removal
>   operations for unsorted data: O(log n) as opposed to O(n) for
>   SortedList(TKey, TValue).
>
> If the list is populated all at once from sorted data,
>   SortedList(TKey, TValue) is faster than SortedDictionary(TKey,
>   TValue).

Comment: Another practical difference, that in `SortedList` you can retrieve by index (as opposed retrieval by key) and in `SortedDictionary` you cannot.

Answer (score 79):

[image]

I'd mention difference between dictionaries.

Above picture shows that `Dictionary<K,V>` is equal or faster in every case than `Sorted` analog, but if order of elements is required, e.g. to print them, `Sorted` one is chosen.

Src: http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/oop-csharp/html/notes/collections-note-time-complexity-dictionaries.html

Comment: Excellent overview. While not in the original question, it should be noted that if you choose between the `Immutable` versions of these dictionaries, that the `Sorted` versions are often actually faster by some 40-50% than the non-sorted counterparts (still `O(log(n))`, but noticeably faster per op). The timings may differ depending on how sorted the input is, though. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638592/111575

Answer (score 28):

To summarize the results of a [Performance Test - SortedList vs. SortedDictionary vs. Dictionary vs. Hashtable](http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/), the results from best to worst for different scenarios:

**Memory Usage:**

```
SortedList<T,T>
Hashtable
SortedDictionary<T,T>
Dictionary<T,T>
```

**Insertions:**

```
Dictionary<T,T>
Hashtable
SortedDictionary<T,T>
SortedList<T,T>
```

**Search Operations:**

```
Hashtable
Dictionary<T,T>
SortedList<T,T>
SortedDictionary<T,T>
```

**foreach loop operations**

```
SortedList<T,T>
Dictionary<T,T>
Hashtable
SortedDictionary<T,T>
```

Comment: When examining these test results, one can question the _raison d'etre_ of SortedDictionary.

Comment: If your `Collection`needs to be `sorted` then you can forget about `Hashtable` and `Dictionary`: if you populate your Collection in one shot -> go for SortedList, but if you anticipate you will often need to `.Add` and `.Remove` items -> go for SortedDictionary.

Comment: Perhaps there is a need to clarify what `sorted` means: when you do a `For Each MyItem in Collection` rather than being processed in the order you originally `.Add`ed the items, a `sorted` `Collection` will process them in an order acording to criterons on the `Key` values (defined in an `IComparer`). For example, if your Keys are Strings, then your Collection will by default be processed per the alphabetical order of your Keys, but you could always define a custom sorting rule.

Answer (score 20):

I can see the proposed answers focus on performance. The article provided below does not provide anything new regarding performance, but it explains the underlying mechanisms. Also note it does not focus on the three `Collection` Types mentioned in the question, but addresses all the Types of the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx

## Extracts:

### Dictionary<>

> The Dictionary is probably the most used associative container class. The Dictionary is the fastest class for associative lookups/inserts/deletes because **it uses a hash table under the covers**. Because the keys are hashed, **the key type should correctly implement GetHashCode() and Equals()** appropriately or you should provide an external IEqualityComparer to the dictionary on construction. The insert/delete/lookup time of items in the dictionary is amortized constant time - O(1) - which means no matter how big the dictionary gets, the time it takes to find something remains relatively constant. This is highly desirable for high-speed lookups. The only **downside** is that the dictionary, by nature of using a hash table, is unordered, so **you cannot easily traverse the items in a Dictionary in order**.

### SortedDictionary<>

> The SortedDictionary is similar to the Dictionary in usage but very different in implementation. The **SortedDictionary uses a binary tree under the covers to maintain the items in order by the key**. As a consequence of sorting, **the type used for the key must correctly implement IComparable** so that the keys can be correctly sorted. The sorted dictionary trades a little bit of lookup time for the ability to maintain the items in order, thus insert/delete/lookup times in a sorted dictionary are logarithmic - O(log n). Generally speaking, with logarithmic time, you can double the size of the collection and it only has to perform one extra comparison to find the item. Use the SortedDictionary when you want fast lookups but also want to be able to maintain the collection in order by the key.

### SortedList<>

> The SortedList is the other sorted associative container class in the generic containers. Once again SortedList, like SortedDictionary, **uses a key to sort key-value pairs**. Unlike SortedDictionary, however, **items in a SortedList are stored as sorted array of items**. This means that insertions and deletions are linear - O(n) - because deleting or adding an item may involve shifting all items up or down in the list. Lookup time, however is O(log n) because the SortedList can use a binary search to find any item in the list by its key. So why would you ever want to do this? Well, the answer is that if you are going to load the SortedList up-front, the insertions will be slower, but because array indexing is faster than following object links, lookups are marginally faster than a SortedDictionary. Once again I'd use this in situations where you want fast lookups and want to maintain the collection in order by the key, and where insertions and deletions are rare.

---

## Tentative Summary of underlying Procedures

**Feedback is very welcome as I am sure I did not get everything right.**

- All arrays are of size `n`.
- Non-sorted array = .Add/.Remove is O(1), but .Item(i) is O(n).
- Sorted array = .Add/.Remove is O(n), but .Item(i) is O(log n).

**Dictionary**

*Memory*

`KeyArray(n) -> non-sorted array<pointer>` 
`ItemArray(n) -> non-sorted array<pointer>` 
`HashArray(n) -> sorted array<hashvalue>`

*Add*

1. Add `HashArray(n) = Key.GetHash` # O(1)
2. Add `KeyArray(n) = PointerToKey` # O(1)
3. Add `ItemArray(n) = PointerToItem` # O(1)

*Remove*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, find `i` where `HashArray(i) = Key.GetHash`  # O(log n) (sorted array)
2. Remove `HashArray(i)` # O(n) (sorted array)
3. Remove `KeyArray(i)` # O(1)
4. Remove `ItemArray(i)` # O(1)

*Get Item*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, find `i` where `HashArray(i) = Key.GetHash` # O(log n) (sorted array)
2. Return `ItemArray(i)`

*Loop Through*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, return `ItemArray(i)`

**SortedDictionary**

*Memory*

`KeyArray(n) = non-sorted array<pointer>` 
`ItemArray(n) = non-sorted array<pointer>` 
`OrderArray(n) = sorted array<pointer>`

*Add*

1. Add `KeyArray(n) = PointerToKey` # O(1)
2. Add `ItemArray(n) = PointerToItem` # O(1)
3. `For i = 0 to n`, find `i` where `KeyArray(i-1) < Key < KeyArray(i)` (using `ICompare`) # O(n)
4. Add `OrderArray(i) = n` # O(n) (sorted array)

*Remove*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, find `i` where `KeyArray(i).GetHash = Key.GetHash` # O(n)
2. Remove `KeyArray(SortArray(i))` # O(n)
3. Remove `ItemArray(SortArray(i))` # O(n)
4. Remove `OrderArray(i)` # O(n) (sorted array)

*Get Item*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, find `i` where `KeyArray(i).GetHash = Key.GetHash` # O(n)
2. Return `ItemArray(i)`

*Loop Through*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, return `ItemArray(OrderArray(i))`

**SortedList**

*Memory*

`KeyArray(n) = sorted array<pointer>` 
`ItemArray(n) = sorted array<pointer>`

*Add*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, find `i` where `KeyArray(i-1) < Key < KeyArray(i)` (using `ICompare`) # O(log n)
2. Add `KeyArray(i) = PointerToKey` # O(n)
3. Add `ItemArray(i) = PointerToItem` # O(n)

*Remove*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, find `i` where `KeyArray(i).GetHash = Key.GetHash` # O(log n)
2. Remove `KeyArray(i)` # O(n)
3. Remove `ItemArray(i)` # O(n)

*Get Item*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, find `i` where `KeyArray(i).GetHash = Key.GetHash` # O(log n)
2. Return `ItemArray(i)`

*Loop Through*

1. `For i = 0 to n`, return `ItemArray(i)`

Answer (score 10):

1. When you want the collection to be sorted by key when you iterate over it. If you don't need your data to be sorted, you're better off with just a Dictionary, it'll have better performance.
2. SortedList and SortedDictionary pretty much do the same thing, but are implemented differently, thus have different strengths and weaknesses [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z658b67.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to assign a **performance score** to each case presented by @Lev, I used the following values:

- O(1) = 3
- O(log n) = 2
- O(n) = 1
- O(1) or O(n) = 2
- O(log n) or O(n) = 1.5

The results are (higher = better):

```
Dictionary:       12.0 
SortedDictionary:  9.0 
SortedList:        6.5
```

Of course, every use-case will give more weight to certain operations.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the weight of O(log n) would be log(n)/log(2) (+1 each time n doubles) whilst the weight of O(n) would be n. So your weighting would be correct  for sizes of up to 4. Anything beyond will see your 2:1 ratio quickly go up. For example if n=100 then you should have O(log n) = 15. Following a similiar thinking, your O(1) would weight 100. Conclusion: O(n) looses the battle fairly quickly. If it does not, it means your array is small, and then efficiency is not a concern.