# Should one prefer ImmutableDictionary, or ImmutableSortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library, immutable-collections

I have heard that the .NET `System.Collections.Immutable` collections are implemented as balanced binary trees in order to satisfy their immutability constraints, even collections which traditionally model hash tables like `Dictionary`, by using the integral value of `GetHashCode` as a sort key.

If I have a type for which it is cheap to generate a hash code, and for which is cheap to compare (e.g. `string` or `int`), and I don't care about the sorted-ness of my collection, would it make sense to prefer `ImmutableSortedDictionary` because the underlying data structure is sorted anyway?

Comment: *If I have a type for which it is cheap to generate a hash code, and for which is cheap to compare (e.g. string or int), and I don't care about the sorted-ness of my collection.* I think you've answered yourself. Keep it simple. From another programmers point of view, i'd be confused to read the code and find out the sortness of a sorted dictionary is useless, leaving me wondering why it was used in the first place.

Comment: @Yuval: Given that the data structure is an AVL tree, IMHO mimicking a hash table interface on top is less "simple".

Comment: Which data structure are you talking about?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: `ImmutableDictionary` and `ImmutableSortedDictionary` (which are both AVL trees)

Comment: Why does that matter then? Why not use the `ImmutableDictionary` if sortness is a non issue

Comment: @Yuval: Because `ImmutableDictionary` *is* sorted. It's just sorted by the numeric value of `GetHashCode` rather than by an intrinsic sort provided by the key type.

Comment: But thats an *implementation detail* which may change at any given time. Do you care about that at all? I'm having a hard time understanding what the benefit of a `ImmutableSortedDictionary` is from your point of view

Comment: @Yuval: It's not an implementation detail any more than Dictionary being a hash table is an implementation detail. The value would be that the sorted-by-T version may be faster in typical use cases than the sorted-by-GetHashCode version in the same way Dictionary is typically faster than SortedDictionary.

Comment: Then why not simply put it to a test? We don't know your data structures and you asked a rather wide question. Wouldn't that be more effective?

Comment: @Yuval: For the same reason I don't build every program ever twice to see if SortedDictionary is faster than Dictionary in the mutable case; I'm looking for the "reasonable default to reach for in most cases".

Answer (score 13):

The answer is **yes**, it can make sense to prefer `ImmutableSortedDictionary` in certain conditions, for instance with `Int32` keys.

In my case, with `Int32` keys I found out that `ImmutableSortedDictionary` was a better pick.

I have run a small benchmark using 1 million items:

- Insert 1,000,000 items in ascending order of key
- Update 1,000,000 random items
- Scan 1,000,000 items, i.e. iterate once over each item in the collection
- Read 1,000,000 random items
- Delete 1,000,000 random items

**ImmutableDictionary<int, object>**

```
Insert: 2499 ms
Update: 7275 ms
Scan:    385 ms
Read:    881 ms
Delete: 5037 ms
```

**ImmutableSortedDictionary<int, object>**

```
Insert: 1808 ms
Update: 4928 ms
Scan:    246 ms
Read:    732 ms
Delete: 3522 ms
```

`ImmutableSortedDictionary` is a bit faster than `ImmutableDictionary` on all operations. Note that insertion was done one item at a time in ascending order of key (because it happens to match my particular use case).

However, you should also consider using a **mutable collection** with some locking. Writing to a mutable `Dictionary<int, object>` is one order of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

A hash-based collection should be significantly faster on .NET because:

1. It can use a more efficient search tree specialized for `int` keys such as a hash trie or Patricia tree.
2. Its inner loop will do almost entirely `int` comparisons rather than generic comparisons.

However, if you need better performance you will usually be much better off switching to a mutable collection like `HashSet`.

Answer (score -3):

It should not really matter. The time complexities from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx) show that while you do get better performance from `Dictionary.Add` than `SortedDictionary.Add` (`O(1)` vs `O(log n)`) both `ImmutableDictionary` and `ImmutableSortedDictionary` have a time complexity of `O(log n)`

Comment: 1. Well, I'm more interested in practical behavior; `ImmutableArray` is much faster to iterate than `ImmutableList`, for example; but has the same complexity. 2. Of course ImmutableDictionary falls back to linear behavior in the event `GetHashCode` values are the same...

Comment: @BillyONeal The one thing that the article was not clear about is the worst case of `ImmuteableSortedDictionary` I am not sure if it is `O(n log n)` or `O(n)`.