# LINQ Query Determine Input is in List Boundaries?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List of longs from a DB query. The total number in the List is always an even number, but the quantity of items can be in the hundreds.

List item [0] is the lower boundary of a "good range", item [1] is the upper boundary of that range. A numeric range between item [1] and item [2] is considered "a bad range".

Sample:

```
var seekset = new SortedList();
var skd= 500;
while( skd< 1000000 )
{
seekset.Add(skd, 0);
skd = skd+ 100;
}
```

If an input number is compared to the List items, if the input number is between 500-600 or 700-800 it is considered "good", but if it is between 600-700 it is considered "bad".

Using the above sample, can anyone comment on the right/fast way to determine if the number 655 is a "bad" number, ie not within any good range boundary (C#, .NET 4.5)?

- If a SortedList is not the proper container for this (eg it needs to be an array), I have no problem changing, the object is static (lower case "s") once it is populated but can be destroyed/repopulated by other threads at any time.

Comment: Where did you get `SortedList<T>` from ?

Comment: @Habib It's in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx

Comment: @DanEsparza, that non generic version, The one used in question is Generic, or is there something I am missing

Comment: @Habib Excellent point.  The closest I can find has 2 type params in the generic constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx

Comment: Also:  Jon Skeet's commentary on the differences between a SortedList and a SortedDictionary may be apropos to the discussion on performance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/935631/19020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, assuming the list is already sorted and both of each pair of limits are treated as "good" values:

```
public static bool IsGood<T>(List<T> list, T value)
{
    int index = list.BinarySearch(value);   
    return index >= 0 || index % 2 == 0;
}
```

Comment: +1: I appreciate the cleverness of this solution.  It is also likely faster than my answer at any scale.

Comment: @KingKing : Good catch. But this is easy to overcome by making the two checks serial if's.

Comment: @KingKing It's correct: if the index is positive then it's an exact match of one of the boundaries, so it's in bounds (according to the assumptions I listed).

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge I didn't doubt your idea, I just thought the `%` operator is not able to perform on a `negative` integer but looks like it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a few hundred items then it's really not *that* bad.  You can just use a regular `List` and do a linear search to find the item.  If the index of the first larger item is even then it's no good, if it's odd then it's good:

```
var index = data.Select((n, i) => new { n, i })
    .SkipWhile(item => someValue < item.n)
    .First().i;

bool isValid = index % 2 == 1;
```

If you have enough items that a linear search isn't desirable then you can use a `BinarySearch` to find the next largest item.

```
var searchValue = data.BinarySearch(someValue);
if (searchValue < 0)
    searchValue = ~searchValue;

bool isValid = searchValue % 2 == 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that LINQ may not be best suited for this problem because IEnumerable forgets about item[0] when it is ready to process item[1].

Yes, this is freshman CS, but the fastest in this case may be just

```
// untested code
Boolean found = false;
for(int i=0; i<seekset.Count; i+=2)
{
   if (valueOfInterest >= seekset[i] &&
       valueOfInterest <= seekset[i+1])
   {
       found = true;
       break;   // or return;
   }
}
```

I apologize for not directly answering your question about "Best approach in Linq", but I sense that you are really asking about best approach for performance.