# Sort 2d points in a list clockwise

Tags: c#, coordinates

Basically I have a list of points, each with X,Y,Z (Z is always the same).

For example:

```
pointList.add(Point p = new Point(1, 2, 3));
```

however I am having trouble sorting them into a clockwise order.

I know the centre and I know the there are roughly 600 points in each list.

I have accomplished this before in Python, but I am having trouble in C#.

Python code:

```
pointlist.sort(key=lambda c:atan2(c[0], c[1]))
```

Comment: Do you want your list to be sorted by default? If so, maybe it would be better to keep the points in one of the `Sorted` collections, using custom `IComparer` ([`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) or [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [their performance differs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/935631/1180426)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this would accomplish what you need.

```
points = points.OrderBy(x => Math.Atan2(x.X, x.Y)).ToList();
```

Not very optimized or anything, just looked at your python code and thought this would accomplish the same.

Note: You may need `using System.Linq` unless you already have it.

Edit:
Sturm pointed out that reversing the order might be necessary to get them 'clock-wise'
One way of accomplishing this is using `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`.

Comment: If you need to iterate through the list 'after' you sort it. A better way of using this would be something like `foreach (var point in points.OrderBy(x => Math.Atan2(x.X, x.Y))) [do stuff with point]` since you're enumerating it 'while' you loop, instead of first enumerating it, then iterating.

Comment: You might need to reverse the order if you want the clockwise order.

Comment: @Sturm what do you mean 'might'? in some cases you will need to reverse and in others you want? how can you tell?

Comment: @t0yk4t it doesnt work in this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590066/finding-the-center-and-sorting-the-coordinates-in-clockwise-direction

Answer (score 4):

For anyone struggling with how to sort around any point `(XX, YY)` not only `(0,0)` the code needs a slight modification.

```cs
points.OrderBy(x => Math.Atan2(x.X - XX, x.Y - YY)).ToList();
```