# Order of printing in Hashtable?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, hashtable, console.writeline

See the example here, i stored values in this order! But  the output i'm getting is different! Why? In what order the Hashtable Storing the Values?

```
      {               
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add("001", "Zara Ali");
        ht.Add("002", "Abida Rehman");
        ht.Add("003", "Joe Holzner");
        ht.Add("004", "Mausam Benazir Nur");
        ht.Add("005", "M. Amlan");
        ht.Add("006", "M. Arif");
        ht.Add("007", "Ritesh Saikia");

        ICollection key = ht.Keys;

        foreach (string k in key)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(k + ": " + ht[k]);
         }

       }
```

**Ouput**

```
006: M. Arif
007: Ritesh Saikia
003: Joe Holzner
002: Abida Rehman
004: Mausam Benazir Nur
001: Zara Ali
005: M. Amlan
```

Comment: You can use `SortedDictionary<K, T>` instead of `HashTable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Hashtable does not guarantee any defined order to the elements within. The implementation of the hashtable splits the values into different buckets based on their Hashcode and its internal implementation, meaning the same values could have different order on different machines, different runs or different versions of the framework. This is because Hashtables are optimized for by-key-retrieval, rather than by-order retrieval.

If you want a collection that can be accessed both by key and in-order, use one of the specialized collections. Judging by your use of `Hashtable` rather than `Dictionary<K,V>`, it's possible you're using .NET 1.1, in which case you can use [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) which will maintain order internally. Newer versions of .NET have `SortedList<K,V>` and `OrderedDictionary<K,V>` which differ a bit in their performance characteristics:

- [What's the difference between SortedList and SortedDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935621/whats-the-difference-between-sortedlist-and-sorteddictionary)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SortedDictionary<K, T>` instead of obsolete `HashTable`:

```
SortedDictionary<String, String> ht = new SortedDictionary<String, String>() {
  {"001", "Zara Ali"},
  {"002", "Abida Rehman"},
  {"003", "Joe Holzner"},
  {"004", "Mausam Benazir Nur"},
  {"005", "M. Amlan"},
  {"006", "M. Arif"},
  {"007", "Ritesh Saikia"}
};

foreach(var pair in ht)
  Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " " + pair.Value);
```

since `Dictionary<K, T>`, `Set<T>`, `HashTable` (note, that `HashTabl`e as well as `ICollection` are *obsolete*) *don't preserve order* you have to use `SortedDictionary<K, T>` and `SortedSet<T`>.

Answer (score 1):

Hashtable does not guarantee any order.You can use `Dictionary<string, string>` you can sorted by Value like you want. You can also use `SortedDictionary<string, string>` this is sorted by key by default.

```
        Dictionary<string, string> ht = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        ht.Add("001", "Zara Ali");
        ht.Add("002", "Abida Rehman");
        ht.Add("003", "Joe Holzner");
        ht.Add("004", "Mausam Benazir Nur");
        ht.Add("005", "M. Amlan");
        ht.Add("006", "M. Arif");
        ht.Add("007", "Ritesh Saikia");

        var order = ht.OrderBy(x => x.Value);//ht.OrderBy(x => x.Key);

        foreach (var k in order)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k.Key + ": " + k.Value);
        }
```