# How to create a SortedList that stores Lists of different data types as values?

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, unity-game-engine

For a Unity game, I'm trying to parse a text file and store the game configurations into a SortedList of keys/values where keys are the names of the features and the values are the feature values which are stored in their own respective lists.

For example a snippet of the text file:

```
Feature1 String Sphere Cube Cylinder
Feature2 Vector4 (0,0,0,255) (255,0,0,0)
Feature3 Int32 2
...
```

How can I create a SortedList that stores these features where I can easily access them through index?

For instance:

```
SortedList[0].Key would return Feature1
SortedList[0].Value would return a list that contains Sphere, Cube, Cylinder
```

------ I've edited to attach my current code for better context------

My current solution prior to asking the question was to create a SortedList so that when I add a new entry, the list of values can be any data type. However, it's a lot of work when I start using and accessing the SortedList because I need to cast the lists inside into the correct types of collection. In the long run, I don't see this being efficient and proper.

Is there a better way to do this using a Sorted List? Or should I implement this with a different data structure?

```
public static SortedList<String, IList> sortedList = new SortedList<String, IList>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IList> data in sortedList) {
    if (data.Key == "Feature1") {
        listShapesSuperblock = new List<string> (data.Value.Cast<string>().ToList());
    }
    if (data.Key == "Feature2") {
        listColorsSuperblock = new List<Vector4> (data.Value.Cast<Vector4>().ToList()); 
    }
    if (data.Key == "Feature3") {
        listContextsSuperblock = new List<Vector4> (data.Value.Cast<Vector4>().ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why store it like that as opposed to a JSON object?

Comment: are you looking for `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` ??  (I have no clue if that works this thursday in Unity, it's too hard to keep up with .Net variations :O )

Comment: aside, I don't see why you wouldn't use a `Dictionary` here

Comment: I didnt consider using a Dictionary because of performance. You can read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935621/whats-the-difference-between-sortedlist-and-sorteddictionary

Comment: Hi Steven. Can you state about how many lines will be in the file. And, can you state about how many times you'll be accessing the info?  ***It is inconceivable that performance is an issue here***.  (if, incredibly, you were actually using this information every frame in some way - for instance, it **becomes a dynamic mesh** or something bizarre, it's absolutely inconceivable you would approach the problem even vaguely like this.)

Comment: @StevenChen That question is comparing `SortedDictionary` (not `Dictionary`) to `SortedList`.  If you just access the items by key (rather than by index), a `Dictionary` is the most performant way.

Comment: @JoeBlow @D Stanley
First, I did mention already that I want to access the items by index...

How many lines will be in the file is very dynamic, it depends on the enhancement of the game. For example, there might be more prefabs or settings that we want to add or change in the future. I'm also not too worried about performance either, I just wanted to let you know why I looked at SortedList instead of SortedDictionary - sorry about the confusion! In summary, the data types for the lists and the amount of configurations in the text file is very dynamic.

Comment: OK.  Let me put it this way.  As far as can be judged by what you have explained, you actually don't want to use a `SortedList` here - again, everyone is purely guessing what your *actual goal* is - but as far as I can guess it, this would just have no connection at all to a `SortedList` which is a specialised thingy, and not really relevant here.

Comment: @JoeBlow Of course, perhaps the best way is not to create a SortedList and that's why there have been many suggestions which I'm very open to! I've also edited my original description with more code to further explain my current approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be using a class structure to access configuration settings. If you use json/xml format, you can deserialize the settings into your class and access them in your code in a type safely manner.

Settings class:

```
class Settings
{
    public List<string> shapes { get; set; }
    public List<Vector> vectors { get; set; }
}
```

Text file:

```
{
    shapes: ["sphere", "cube"]
}
```

Usage:

```
var settings = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Settings>(readTextFile); 
string firstShape = settings.shapes.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: An excellent answer.  I now fear though that the OP is "off track" on the whole question, unfortunately.  The OP mentioning "performance" suggests an unusual use case.  It is inconceivable there could be a "performance" issue in some settings.

Comment: Actually I thought deserialization occurs only once through life time of the process, at the very beginning. After the first reading, one can keep a singleton instance of the settings class. it will be very fast to read values of the properties after filling thme once.

Comment: faster than sorted list or dictionary.

Comment: Hi Abdullah *"I thought deserialization occurs only once through life time of the process"* yes, of course you're right.  I was saying, I fear the OP could be muddled-up about what the OP needs. Just FTR, iterally using singletons is problematic in Unity; usual is just something trivial like http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1128034/view.html

Comment: Yes, singleton was problematic in unity, I didn't know about that. But wouldn't having a dictionary means a singleton of some kind?

Comment: You know, all you'd do there is use a trivial `public static class`, the perfect way to hold "globals" like settings etc. It's that simple.

Comment: If you need a **MonoBehaviour** as such that is "singleton-like", you just do this http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1128034/view.html  Note that the concept of "singletons", as well as working poorly in Unity, just conceptually make little sense in a game scene (or indeed in the real world).  "Everything is" a single item, of course, in a game scene. (Or the real world.)

Comment: Hey @AbdullahNehir is there a way to this without the need to create a class?

Comment: @JoeBlow My question is pretty clear. I hope you can just take it as it is like everyone else. If I worry about performance, I would state it in the original description. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi @StevenChen, deserializing into a dictionary can be done. A solution is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in C# without casting your lists to a collection of object.

Basically this sounds like a typical memory cache which would represent the values as an object, which you would have to cast back into the appropriate type yourself.

If every value will be a collection, then you could represent it as a sorted list of `IEnumerable<object>` or just `object`:

`var sortedList = new SortedList<string, IEnumerable<object>>();
var sortedList = new SortedList<string, object>();`

I would prefer the latter one, because it would be easier to handle.